# Assigning values to Flutter widgets

Tags: flutter, dart

Sizedbox, container and similar widgets border radius, height, width is better to give `int` value or `double`?
How does this affect the speed and quality of the program?

Which is better

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please provide further details about in what situation you have this choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not matter, in this specific example. The [`Container` constructor](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Container/Container.html) takes `double?` for `width` and `height` so if you are providing integers, they will just be converted into `double` by the compiler when compiling the application. So no difference at all when running the program.